# Recognizing spaces in java

Tags: java

I'm a newb and I started out trying out some things, so I made a calculator that only required one line. It works when I do it in this format : Int space String space int. EG : 10 + 50. If I don't do spaces like 50+50 the program fails. Is there someway to recognise spaces in Java? Bare in mind that I'm a noob but I find that I did a great job that keeped me motivated. Here's teh code :

```
package Tests;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your values : ");
    int first = input.nextInt();
    String character = input.next();
    int second = input.nextInt();
    int answer = 0;


    switch (character) {
    case "*":
        answer = first * second;
        break;
    case "/":
        answer = first/second;
        break;
    case "-":
        answer = first-second;
        break;
    case "+":
        answer = first+second;
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Failed to recognise character");
        break;

    }

    System.out.println("Answer : " + answer);
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Scanner#next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) reads the next token from the input string based on whatever delimiter you have set for your `Scanner` object when you create it. The default delimiter is whitespace, so when you space out the operands and operator your program processes them correctly. You *could* set the delimiters for your Scanner as the operators.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
input.useDelimiter("\+|\-|\*|\\");
```

and your program will function properly.

Comment: Much better than my answer for his simple use case :)

Comment: Keep in mind this only works for binary operators. Something like negation would fail here without addition checks.

Comment: Well, this throws in another error : Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ ) - Thanks in advance, sorry if I missed anything but I'm still learning alot.

Comment: You have to use escaped backslashes in regex strings in Java, so the line would be `input.useDelimiter("\\+|\\-|\\*|\\\\");`

Comment: But then how do you determine which operator was used?

Answer (score 1):

There are some convenience methods in Scanner that you're using now (i.e. `nextInt()`) but for your purpose you should probably just get the `nextLine()` and do some more complex parsing of the expression.

This is probably too much and I wouldn't make this my main focus right now if I were you, but eventually you may want to read up about formal languages and use tooling such as http://www.antlr.org/ for purposes like these.

Comment: Well my idea was to have a calculator that functioned like 50 + 50 on one line and not : 50 (next line) + (next line) 50 (next line)

If you know what I mean.

Comment: In the case of nextLine() you would have the full String, for example 50+50 and then you could extract the expression and divide it up into parts from there.
For a simple solution for this exact use case you can also do what Hunter McMillen suggested. I would actually recommend that and not focus on formal languages when you're just getting into programming :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not with Java not handling white spaces right, the problem is with Scanner class which uses white space as a separator (way to distinguish different pieces) by default.
You can still use Scanner class but you'll need some basic Regular Expression knowledge to achieve what you're trying to do.

For Java beginner it would be better to do some basic string processing. You just need to do `input.nextLine()` and parse the string contents.

Keywords you're looking for are `indexOf, substring, trim and Integer.parseInt()`